# How to download excel file using the windows application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have master excel file with predefined template which will keep in project folder.

Now I need to download the file using the Windows application or WPF.
I have tried with following code but it did't work for me. So could you please help me for the same?
Thanks a lot for your support.

```
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string sourcePath = Application.StartupPath;
    File.Copy(sourcePath + "\\filename.xls", saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: You should probably assign some build action to the excel file (like `content` or `embedded resource`) and then work on the file in your deployment instead of whatever you try right now. But you need to describe your problem in more detail for any useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it should be:

```
File.Copy(sourcePath + "\\filename.xls", saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

Both `savefileDialog` references should be the same and they should reference an object already defined with that same name.